# Configuring Django

Tags: python, django, macos, django-settings

I just installed Django 1.6 on OS X 10.8 with python 2.7 and am having trouble going through the tutorial. After setting creating a server called mysite by running:

```
django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

I then cd'ed into mysite and ran

```
python manage.py runserver
```

and got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in execute
    translation.activate('en-us')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 130, in activate
    return _trans.activate(language)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 188, in activate
    _active.value = translation(language)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 177, in translation
    default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 159, in _fetch
    app = import_module(appname)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.sites import AdminSite, site
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.admin.forms import AdminAuthenticationForm
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/forms.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 361, in <module>
    class AbstractUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 212, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class(field.name, copy.deepcopy(field))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 264, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 303, in contribute_to_class
    cls._meta.add_field(self)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 172, in add_field
    self.local_fields.insert(bisect(self.local_fields, field), field)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/functools.py", line 56, in <lambda>
    '__lt__': [('__gt__', lambda self, other: other < self),
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/functools.py", line 56, in <lambda>
.........
```

this error ends up being repeatedly printed until the end:

**File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/functools.py", line 56, in 
            '_*lt*_': [('_*gt*_', lambda self, other: other < self),**

And here are the last few lines of output:

```
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/functools.py", line 56, in <lambda>
    '__lt__': [('__gt__', lambda self, other: other < self),
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/functools.py", line 56, in <lambda>
    '__lt__': [('__gt__', lambda self, other: other < self),
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/functools.py", line 56, in <lambda>
    '__lt__': [('__gt__', lambda self, other: other < self),
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

After looking at the last line:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I also ran:

```
django-admin.py check
```

and got this output:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I also tried setting my environment variable in tcsh by typing in:

```
setenv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE "mysite.settings"
```

but it still gave me the recursion depth error. Running

```
django-admin.py check
```

then gave me this error:

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'mysite.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named mysite.settings
```

Here is my settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)

import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '3e%g^*y!3$2=ln75%usf2ftjf&urt7&kuj@_-yc+53pjm)$@9^'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

And my file structure:

```
mysite/
 manage.py
 mysite/
  __init__.py
  settings.py
  urls.py
  __init__.pyc
  settings.pyc
  wsgi.py
```

I am a newbie at django and am really stuck. Can anyone offer some insight?

Comment: Please post your `settings.py` and the last lines of the traceback you get when running `manage.py runserver`.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers the error ends up repeating 'File /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/functools.py", line 56, in <lambda> '__lt__': [('__gt__', lambda self, other: other < self),` until the end

Comment: What is in your env variable? there should be the directory in which the settings file is

Comment: I just solved it by upgrading from Python 2.7.2 to 2.7.6. See the answer I posted. Unfortunately I don't have a saved printout of my previous environment variable so it's hard to compare the difference between that the new environment variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I finally found the answer. Apparently the error was a result of Python 2.7.2. Once I upgraded to 2.7.6, the problem went away.

Here is a similar thread where I found the answer:

[maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp error while executing python manage.py runserver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16369637/maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded-in-cmp-error-while-executing-python-manage-py-r?rq=1)

Don't know why this solution didn't show up in my searches when I was creating this thread...

Comment: @dig Are you still getting this error? Not sure what specs and version of Django your computer has, but for OS X when you run "python -V" on the command line you should get "Python 2.7.6". Also, are you running Django with an IDE?

Comment: Actually I found a typo in code and after fix error disappeared, however error text was the same :-)

Comment: Hey @theNinja I am facing same problem with python 2.7.13 version. Can you tell what exact reason for that.

Answer (score 18):

Check in `manage.py` if you have this:

```
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
```

And in `wsgi.py` this:

```
import os

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
```

Also, any python scripts that integrate Django should look like this:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
# Uncomment below for Django 1.7 +
#import django
#django.setup()
```

Comment: Yes these lines are all there.

Comment: This answer brought me closer to the solution. For anyone that is having trouble integrating Django into an external script make sure to set the environment variable in the beginning of the script even before all of your imports, but after the os import of course.