# django.core.exceptions ImproperlyConfigured error when running selenium functional test in python

Tags: python, django, selenium, data-migration

I've had a similar problem to this one before where I received a nearly identical error message, i.e.

```
C:\Users\David J\optilab\optilab_project>python functional_tests.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "functional_tests.py", line 4, in <module>
    from optilab.models import Design
  File "C:\Users\David J\optilab\optilab_project\optilab\models.py", line 10, in <module>
    class Design(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\David J\optilab\optilab_project\optilab\models.py", line 11, in Design
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1072, in __init__
    super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 166, in __init__
    self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

But it was being produced because I was calling my test incorrectly from the shell.  Now I am attempting to run a functional test, which I have done several times before successfully using the command
 `"python functional_tests.py"` 
in my project folder -- but it produces the above error message.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, or why this may have worked before but not now?  thank.

Edit:
Here is functional_tests.py:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import unittest
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from optilab.models import Design
from automa.api import *

class HomeTest(unittest.TestCase):  

    def setUp(self):  
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.browser.get('http://localhost:8000/lab')
        self.new_design = self.browser.find_element_by_id("new_design")
        self.load_design = self.browser.find_element_by_id("load_test")
        self.design_name = self.browser.find_element_by_id("design_name")
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)

    def test_latest_designs_displayed_in_table(self):
        # 

        self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)
        self.design_table = self.browser.find_element_by_id("design_table")
        self.rows = self.browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
        self.assertTrue(
            any(row.text == 'My First Design' for row in rows),
            "New design did not appear in test table."
        )

    def test_entering_text_activates_new(self):
        # user enters name of design.  new becomes clickable.            
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)
        self.design_name.send_keys("sample_design")

    def test_new_test_can_be_saved_and_retrieved(self):
        name = "sample design"
        self.design_name.send_keys(name)
        self.new_design.click()
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)
        self.saved_design = Design.objects.get(name=design_name)

    def test_entering_name_of_previously_saved_test_activates_load(self): 
        # user enters the name of a previously saved test.  load button becomes clickable.
        design = Design(name="sample_design")
        saved_design = Design.objects.get(id=1).name
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)
        self.design_name.send_keys(saved_design)
        self.load_design.click()

    def test_entering_name_of_previously_saved_test_but_clicking_new_prompts_overwrite(self):
        # user entes name of saved test but clicks new.  dialogue box asks if test should be overwritten.
        previously_saved_design = Design.objects.get(id=1).name
        self.design_name.send_keys(previously_saved_design)                    

    def test_clicking_save_redirects_to_model(self):
        pass

    def tearDown(self):  
        self.browser.quit()



if __name__ == '__main__':  

unittest.main()
```

Comment: Can you show `functional_tests.py`? You probably need to set the settings module (`os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"]`) and/or call `django.setup()`.

Comment: @knbk  I added functional_tests.py.  Where can I set the settings module?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configuring Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794901/configuring-django)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The start of your script should look something like this

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "optilab.settings") # or whatever
import django
django.setup()


from selenium import webdriver
import unittest
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from optilab.models import Design
from automa.api import *  # try not to do this
```

Comment: Using this verbatim gives me an ImportError (no module named settings_stream).  I'm not sure how to change this to work with my personal project..

Comment: Oops sorry. Copy paste error! I copied from one of my selenium tests where my settings file is named settings_stream. Updated the answer with correct one

Comment: Now it's saying "importerror: no module named settings".

Comment: where is your settings.py?

Comment: optilab_project/optilab_project/settings.py.  functional_tests.py is located in optilab_project.

Comment: then "optilab.settings" is correct.  Unless you have a misconfigured project. Look at manage.py and copy paste what's used there

Comment: Then I guess my project is misconfigured -- manage.py says "optilab_project.settings".  Using that, I'm now getting the error: "django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet."  This is incredibly annoying, I'm thinking about just starting over.

Comment: Sorry slight error on my part. django.setup() call should be a few lines higher in the source code (updated answer)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because Django has not been correctly setup before trying to call settings, it has no way to know which project settings should be used without the `"DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"` variable and the `django.setup()` call is essential to import models and access the database. (see [e4c5's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38064596/3930971) for that method)

However, this is not the recommended method or the easiest one. You can call the functional tests just like the unit tests from `manage.py test` and Django will automagically setup everything for you, it'll even use a tempdb for functional tests. If your functional tests include insertions and updates in the functional tests (and you should) a tempdb comes in handy.

To use this facility though, you must change a few things in your code.

First there is the matter of the filename, the default pattern for `manage.py test`([doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests)) is "test*.py", you can change this with `-p` or `--pattern` but the usual solution is to rename functional_tests.py to tests.py and place it inside a functional_tests folder. That way you can call just the functional tests by calling `manage.py test functional_tests`.

Also, instead of importing TestCase from unittest you should look into using `TestCase`([doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/testing/tools/#testcase)) from `django.test` or even `LiveServerTestCase`([doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/testing/tools/#liveservertestcase)) which would save you the trouble of running `manage.py runserver` yourself.